# Installing downloaded tar.gz files with pip

Tags: python, pip, pygui

When I download `PyGUI-2.5.4.tar.gz` from http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/ and then run

```
pip install downloads/PyGUI-2.5.4.tar.gz
```

I get a long error, the root of which appears to be the following:

```
tarfile.ReadError: not a gzip file
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is downloads/ ? is that a directory ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry for lack of clarity.

Comment: In case this helps others, I got this error when trying to do this on an archive I downloaded via curl. Upon closer inspection (by running `cat` on my archive), I saw that the actual contents were simply `{"message":"404 File Not Found"}%`... Explains why I couldn't pip install it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install tar.gz with pip Install a particular source archive file.

```
pip install ./Package-1.0.4.tar.gz
```

You can also install it with extracting tar.gz file. First you should extract it using using tar command.

```
tar -xzvf PyGUI-2.5.4.tar.gz
cd PyGUI-2.5.4.tar.gz
```

And then use the setup.py file to install the package .

```
python setup.py install
```

or

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

( use sudo only in linux )

Source: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

Comment: I had to use "python setup.py install"

Comment: No, you can install tar.gz with pip https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

"Install a particular source archive file.

$ pip install ./downloads/SomePackage-1.0.4.tar.gz
$ pip install http://my.package.repo/SomePackage-1.0.4.zip"

Comment: i use `python3 -m pip install .` Once i'm in the folder. `python3 -m pip install /tmp/test.tar.gz` works too, with the gzip of the `.` folder.

Answer (score 10):

The correct syntax for the installation is:

```
pip install --user ./Downloads/PyGUI-2.5.4.tar.gz
```

The `--user` is used to give the necessary permissions to install the package. Always check for the correct path and Upper and Lower case in your path(Your path was to 'downloads' with small 'd' ).

Comment: Helped me on windows.